# Disabling or Increasing Timeout interval for RabbitMQ SpringBoot Amqp Connection Exception in local

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I have a spring boot project that uses Spring AMPQ, no issues with hosting, I just want to disable the infinite retry connection locally or at least increase the time between retry attempts.

```
2022-08-16 13:56:42.849  INFO 40008 --- [           main] o.s.c.s.binder.DefaultBinderFactory      : Creating binder: rabbit
2022-08-16 13:56:43.165  INFO 40008 --- [           main] o.s.c.s.binder.DefaultBinderFactory      : Caching the binder: rabbit
2022-08-16 13:56:43.165  INFO 40008 --- [           main] o.s.c.s.binder.DefaultBinderFactory      : Retrieving cached binder: rabbit
2022-08-16 13:56:43.271  INFO 40008 --- [           main] c.s.b.r.p.RabbitExchangeQueueProvisioner : declaring queue for inbound: springCloudBus.anonymous.4IzJRJtxT1afyh0KS7yI5w, bound to: springCloudBus
2022-08-16 13:56:43.274  INFO 40008 --- [           main] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [localhost:5672]
2022-08-16 13:56:47.371  INFO 40008 --- [           main] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [localhost:5672]
2022-08-16 13:56:51.460  INFO 40008 --- [           main] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [localhost:5672]
2022-08-16 13:56:55.627  INFO 40008 --- [           main] o.s.c.stream.binder.BinderErrorChannel   : Channel 'springCloudBus.anonymous.4IzJRJtxT1afyh0KS7yI5w.errors' has 1 subscriber(s).
2022-08-16 13:56:55.628  INFO 40008 --- [           main] o.s.c.stream.binder.BinderErrorChannel   : Channel 'springCloudBus.anonymous.4IzJRJtxT1afyh0KS7yI5w.errors' has 2 subscriber(s).
2022-08-16 13:56:55.630  INFO 40008 --- [           main] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [localhost:5672]
2022-08-16 13:56:59.673  INFO 40008 --- [           main] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Broker not available; cannot force queue declarations during start: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
2022-08-16 13:56:59.679  INFO 40008 --- [1afyh0KS7yI5w-1] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [localhost:5672]
2022-08-16 13:57:03.931  INFO 40008 --- [           main] o.s.i.a.i.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter      : started bean 'inbound.springCloudBus.anonymous.4IzJRJtxT1afyh0KS7yI5w'
2022-08-16 13:57:04.059  INFO 40008 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2022-08-16 13:57:05.110  INFO 40008 --- [           main] d.s.w.p.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper : Context refreshed
2022-08-16 13:57:05.140  INFO 40008 --- [           main] d.s.w.p.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper : Found 1 custom documentation plugin(s)
2022-08-16 13:57:05.255  INFO 40008 --- [           main] s.d.s.w.s.ApiListingReferenceScanner     : Scanning for api listing references
2022-08-16 13:57:05.362  INFO 40008 --- [           main] .d.s.w.r.o.CachingOperationNameGenerator : Generating unique operation named: getApplicationFeedbackUsingGET_1
2022-08-16 13:57:05.404  INFO 40008 --- [           main] .d.s.w.r.o.CachingOperationNameGenerator : Generating unique operation named: getListUsingGET_1
2022-08-16 13:57:05.760  INFO 40008 --- [           main] o.s.i.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter   : Registering MessageChannel springCloudBus.anonymous.4IzJRJtxT1afyh0KS7yI5w.errors
2022-08-16 13:57:06.992  INFO 40008 --- [22)-19.3.148.44] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [localhost:5672]
2022-08-16 13:57:07.156  INFO 40008 --- [21)-19.3.148.44] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-08-16 13:57:07.156  INFO 40008 --- [21)-19.3.148.44] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-08-16 13:57:07.159  INFO 40008 --- [21)-19.3.148.44] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 3 ms
2022-08-16 13:57:09.206  WARN 40008 --- [1afyh0KS7yI5w-1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it. Exception summary: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
2022-08-16 13:57:09.209  INFO 40008 --- [1afyh0KS7yI5w-1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Restarting Consumer@1727d525: tags=[[]], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
2022-08-16 13:57:11.086  INFO 40008 --- [1afyh0KS7yI5w-2] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [localhost:5672]
2022-08-16 13:57:11.125  WARN 40008 --- [22)-19.3.148.44] o.s.b.a.amqp.RabbitHealthIndicator       : Rabbit health check failed

org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:602) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:724) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:252) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:2163) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:2136) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:2116) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.amqp.RabbitHealthIndicator.getVersion(RabbitHealthIndicator.java:49) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.amqp.RabbitHealthIndicator.doHealthCheck(RabbitHealthIndicator.java:44) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.AbstractHealthIndicator.health(AbstractHealthIndicator.java:82) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicator.getHealth(HealthIndicator.java:37) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.getHealth(HealthEndpoint.java:71) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.getHealth(HealthEndpoint.java:39) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:99) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getAggregateHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:110) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:96) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:74) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:61) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.health(HealthEndpoint.java:65) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.health(HealthEndpoint.java:55) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:282) ~[spring-core-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.invoke.reflect.ReflectiveOperationInvoker.invoke(ReflectiveOperationInvoker.java:74) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.AbstractDiscoveredOperation.invoke(AbstractDiscoveredOperation.java:60) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.EndpointMBean.invoke(EndpointMBean.java:121) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.EndpointMBean.invoke(EndpointMBean.java:96) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809) ~[na:na]
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) ~[na:na]
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466) ~[na:na]
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307) ~[na:na]
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1399) ~[na:na]
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:827) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor157.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:107) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609) ~[na:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandlerFactory.create(SocketFrameHandlerFactory.java:60) ~[amqp-client-5.12.0.jar:5.12.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1220) ~[amqp-client-5.12.0.jar:5.12.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1170) ~[amqp-client-5.12.0.jar:5.12.0]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.connectAddresses(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:640) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.connect(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:615) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:565) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
    ... 49 common frames omitted

2022-08-16 13:57:15.193  INFO 40008 --- [22)-19.3.148.44] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [localhost:5672]
2022-08-16 13:57:19.294  WARN 40008 --- [22)-19.3.148.44] o.s.b.a.amqp.RabbitHealthIndicator       : Rabbit health check failed

org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:602) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:724) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:252) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:2163) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:2136) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:2116) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.amqp.RabbitHealthIndicator.getVersion(RabbitHealthIndicator.java:49) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.amqp.RabbitHealthIndicator.doHealthCheck(RabbitHealthIndicator.java:44) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.AbstractHealthIndicator.health(AbstractHealthIndicator.java:82) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicator.getHealth(HealthIndicator.java:37) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.getHealth(HealthEndpoint.java:71) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.getHealth(HealthEndpoint.java:39) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:99) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getAggregateHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:110) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:96) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getAggregateHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:110) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:96) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:74) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:61) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.health(HealthEndpoint.java:65) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.health(HealthEndpoint.java:55) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:282) ~[spring-core-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.invoke.reflect.ReflectiveOperationInvoker.invoke(ReflectiveOperationInvoker.java:74) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.AbstractDiscoveredOperation.invoke(AbstractDiscoveredOperation.java:60) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.EndpointMBean.invoke(EndpointMBean.java:121) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.EndpointMBean.invoke(EndpointMBean.java:96) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809) ~[na:na]
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) ~[na:na]
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466) ~[na:na]
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307) ~[na:na]
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1399) ~[na:na]
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:827) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor157.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:107) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609) ~[na:na]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandlerFactory.create(SocketFrameHandlerFactory.java:60) ~[amqp-client-5.12.0.jar:5.12.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1220) ~[amqp-client-5.12.0.jar:5.12.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1170) ~[amqp-client-5.12.0.jar:5.12.0]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.connectAddresses(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:640) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.connect(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:615) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:565) ~[spring-rabbit-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
    ... 51 common frames omitted

2022-08-16 13:57:20.269  WARN 40008 --- [1afyh0KS7yI5w-2] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it. Exception summary: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
2022-08-16 13:57:20.269  INFO 40008 --- [1afyh0KS7yI5w-2] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Restarting Consumer@92cb521: tags=[[]], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
2022-08-16 13:57:20.270  INFO 40008 --- [1afyh0KS7yI5w-3] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [localhost:5672]
2022-08-16 13:57:29.439  WARN 40008 --- [1afyh0KS7yI5w-3] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it. Exception summary: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
2022-08-16 13:57:29.439  INFO 40008 --- [1afyh0KS7yI5w-3] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Restarting Consumer@3fa71956: tags=[[]], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
2022-08-16 13:57:29.440  INFO 40008 --- [1afyh0KS7yI5w-4] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [localhost:5672]
2022-08-16 13:57:38.593  WARN 40008 --- [1afyh0KS7yI5w-4] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it. Exception summary: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
2022-08-16 13:57:38.593  INFO 40008 --- [1afyh0KS7yI5w-4] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Restarting Consumer@54a50d69: tags=[[]], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
2022-08-16 13:57:38.593  INFO 40008 --- [1afyh0KS7yI5w-5] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [localhost:5672]
```

Trying to increase the back off interval doesn't seem to do anything.

```
@Configuration
@EnableRabbit
@Profile("!cloud")
public class LocalConfiguration
{
    @Bean
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
    {
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory simpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        simpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        ExponentialBackOff exponentialBackOff = new ExponentialBackOff(100, 3.0);
        simpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory.setRecoveryBackOff(exponentialBackOff);
        return simpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory;
    }

}
```

Is there a way to increase the timeout or disable the constant retries?

Comment: Your recovery attempts are 9 seconds apart; so something changed - the default is 5 seconds. Show more logs (edit the question, don't try to put it in comments).

Comment: Added a bit more logs

Answer (score 0):

I just copied your factory and it works exactly as expected:

```
2022-08-16 14:03:06.012  WARN 97694 --- [ 127.0.0.1:5672] c.r.c.impl.ForgivingExceptionHandler     : An unexpected connection driver error occurred (Exception message: Connection reset)
2022-08-16 14:03:06.499  INFO 97694 --- [ntContainer#0-1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Restarting Consumer@30c31dd7: tags=[[amq.ctag-v4isXkIaMAAe_NHmUnHMzg]], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,1), conn: Proxy@24be2d9c Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@41200e0c [delegate=amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/, localPort= 61142], acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
2022-08-16 14:03:06.502  INFO 97694 --- [ntContainer#0-2] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [localhost:5672]
2022-08-16 14:03:06.712  WARN 97694 --- [ntContainer#0-2] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it. Exception summary: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2022-08-16 14:03:06.712  INFO 97694 --- [ntContainer#0-2] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Restarting Consumer@2a884e96: tags=[[]], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
2022-08-16 14:03:06.714  INFO 97694 --- [ntContainer#0-3] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [localhost:5672]
2022-08-16 14:03:07.125  WARN 97694 --- [ntContainer#0-3] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it. Exception summary: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2022-08-16 14:03:07.126  INFO 97694 --- [ntContainer#0-3] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Restarting Consumer@28a5e291: tags=[[]], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
2022-08-16 14:03:07.170  INFO 97694 --- [ntContainer#0-4] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [localhost:5672]
2022-08-16 14:03:08.186  WARN 97694 --- [ntContainer#0-4] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it. Exception summary: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2022-08-16 14:03:08.186  INFO 97694 --- [ntContainer#0-4] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Restarting Consumer@7e1e240: tags=[[]], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
2022-08-16 14:03:08.187  INFO 97694 --- [ntContainer#0-5] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [localhost:5672]
2022-08-16 14:03:11.022  WARN 97694 --- [ntContainer#0-5] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it. Exception summary: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2022-08-16 14:03:11.023  INFO 97694 --- [ntContainer#0-5] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Restarting Consumer@5285c94: tags=[[]], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
2022-08-16 14:03:11.025  INFO 97694 --- [ntContainer#0-6] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [localhost:5672]
2022-08-16 14:03:19.328  WARN 97694 --- [ntContainer#0-6] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it. Exception summary: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2022-08-16 14:03:19.329  INFO 97694 --- [ntContainer#0-6] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Restarting Consumer@7500ff90: tags=[[]], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
2022-08-16 14:03:19.330  INFO 97694 --- [ntContainer#0-7] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [localhost:5672]
2022-08-16 14:03:43.661  WARN 97694 --- [ntContainer#0-7] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it. Exception summary: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2022-08-16 14:03:43.662  INFO 97694 --- [ntContainer#0-7] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Restarting Consumer@70a5660e: tags=[[]], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
2022-08-16 14:03:43.664  INFO 97694 --- [ntContainer#0-8] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [localhost:5672]
2022-08-16 14:04:13.679  WARN 97694 --- [ntContainer#0-8] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it. Exception summary: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2022-08-16 14:04:13.680  INFO 97694 --- [ntContainer#0-8] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Restarting Consumer@a7d0a48: tags=[[]], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
2022-08-16 14:04:13.682  INFO 97694 --- [ntContainer#0-9] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [localhost:5672]
```

The last retry is 30 seconds apart (which is the default max for an `ExponentialBackOff` (100ms, 300ms, 900ms, 2.7s, 8s, 24s, 30s).

Some retries have nothing to do with the listener container, it is the `RabbitHealthIndicator` that is trying to connect.

Your container retries appear to be a `FixedBackOff` of 9 seconds so something doesn't add up.